# why this twelve column don't show inline?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

so strange behaviour I meet in bootply. I want to understand why I have this result with twelve column grid. This behaviour run with xs, sm, md, lg column type.

Perhaps for more understand grid system bootstrap 3...but I believed that 12 column all the time and type of column.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 vcenter">
            <span class="label label-primary">bla</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 vcenter">
            <p class="textPres">Ava "fefefeef
                feeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
                fggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
                gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
                gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Bootply : [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/115821#)

Comment: I believe it's `float: none` that is causing you the problem.

Comment: If I erase `float: none` the first element(label) lose his vertical align display